# OpenGL specular lighting is static

Tags: opengl, lighting

I am drawing 3d shapes in OpenGL. I am trying to add specular lighting to an object, but it doesn't seem to work. I have done ray tracing, so I know that specular lighting depends on the camera's position. In OpenGL, however, I have a static light spot.
Example:
[image]

The bright spot on the left of the arrow shaped object doesn't move, no matter where I view the object from. My light source is in line with the sphere and the arrow. It is a directional light. The shiny spot, however, doesn't move with the camera, it's completely static. It also doesn't appear on the other side of the arrow, where the light hits it from the same angle. Is this how it's supposed to work? How can I get it to move?

Comment: you probably move the light along with the camera

Comment: @ratchetfreak The objects are not reflecting diffuse light from the other side, so I don't think that's the case. Also, the camera can move up and down. The light spot stays there even if I view the object from below.

Comment: then it might be how you calculate the reflection vector

Comment: Can we please see some glsl code to see how you're calculating the specular highlight?

Comment: I bet its to do with placing camera view transforms in the projection matrix!

Comment: @jozxyqk Yes, that was it. I figured it out about 2 days ago. It's working fine now :D